# how to load jsf application sits behind apache reverse proxy

Tags: apache, jsf-2, proxy

I have a jsf 2.x web app serving incoming requests behind apache reverse proxy server. The app name is "foo" hosted on tomcat server in which fqdn is "fooweb.com" and the reverse proxy server's fqdn is "barweb.com".

So I created foo_conf file in the proxy server having following directive:

```
<VirtualHost *:4443>
    ServerName barweb.com
    ProxyPass /foo https://fooweb.com:8443/foo
    ProxyPassReverse /foo https://fooweb.com:8443/foo
</VirtualHost>
```

Three scenarios I observed after restarting the proxy server:

1. If I don't go through reverse proxy server, I have access to resources by entering url of "https://fooweb.com/foo/faces/index.xhtml"
2. If I go through the proxy server entering url of "https://barweb.com/foo" the server returns "http status 404 - /foo/" to a client.
3. If I fully specify resource and pass to the proxy server such as "https://barweb.com/foo/faces/index.xhtml" then I have access to resources just fine.

What I would like to achieve is entering "https://barweb.com/foo" would properly points to "https://barweb.com/foo/faces/index.xhtml". I'd appreciate your advice and guidance on this matter. Thank you!

Comment: adding following directive did a trick. "RewriteRule ^/foo/$ /foo/faces/index.xhtml [R]". Hope this could be helpful to others.

Comment: Server admin questions belong at our sister site http://serverfault.com